# Use PHP or Perl to properly rotate JPEG images

Tags: php, perl, jpeg, rotation, exif

I used F-Spot on Ubuntu to rotate some photos (JPEG files) before I FTPed them up to my website. This seemed to work just fine. However, if those images are opened in a web browser, they do not show as rotated. Nor do they if I download them to a Windows Vista machine and open them with any standard program there. I suspect that F-Spot rotates images by modifying the exif data or similar, not by actually rotating the images.

So I want a little function which will run on my web server (i.e., PHP or Perl) which will accept an array of file paths, examine the images, and rotate those which need to be rotated, overwriting the original file.

I know some PHP but no Perl.

---

In the course of searching to see whether this question had already been asked, I came across some ideas. I might be able, after some trial and error, to knock something together using glob(), exif_read_data(), and imagerotate(). I'll try tomorrow. But now I'm going to bed.

Comment: Just a note: your closing remarks are causing people to want to close your question as "no longer relevant" and could discourage answers, so you might want to omit that next time. :)

Comment: Just use the command line `convert` utility that comes with ImageMagick to rotate the images and upload them to your site instead of writing a server side solution. Note that both answers provided would rotate the images on each access. If you are replacing the original file with a rotated image each time the image is accessed, the effect would be *interesting*.

Comment: To clarify: Thanks for the help in rotating images. What I really need help with, though, is in examining the images to work out which ones need to be rotated. And I really do want a server-side solution, because my laptop took most of two days to upload all those images, and I don't fancy doing that again.

Obviously the images have some flag in them which tells F-Spot to show them rotated. How can I find that flag and rotate only images which have it? I'll have a look for it in the exif data, but the php manual for the function exif_read_data() doesn't look hopeful.

Comment: And no. I can't see anything relevant in the exif data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Perl, I think you want ["exiftool -Orientation"](http://search.cpan.org/~exiftool/Image-ExifTool-7.89/exiftool). The PHP equivalent seems to be accessible through ["exif_read_data"](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-read-data.php).

Comment: Now, why didn't I think of searching for "orientation"? That's brilliant. There's even some code shown in the php manual comments from mafo which I'll be able to use.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-read-data.php

Comment: It's always easier to phrase the question when you know the answer!

Comment: I still haven't got it quite working, but I know where I'm going now. When I have some actual working code I'll post it here.

Answer (score 3):

In Perl you can rotate images using the [Image::Magick](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Image::Magick) module. There's a [PHP interface](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/perl-magick.php) too, and a command-line interface (I think). If you're just rotating a few images you're probably best off with the command line version.

Here's a simple Perl script to rotate images clockwise (and preserves the files' modification time):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Image::Magick;

die "no filename specified!\n" if not @ARGV;

foreach my $filename (@ARGV)
{
    print "Processing: $filename\n";

    # Get the file's last modified time for restoring later
    my $mtime = (stat $filename)[9];

    my $image = Image::Magick->new;
    my $result = $image->Read($filename);
    warn "$result" if $result;
    $result = $image->Rotate(degrees => 90.0);
    warn "$result" if $result;
    $result = $image->Write($filename);
    warn "$result" if $result;

    # Restore the mtime
    utime time, $mtime, $filename;
}
```

Comment: you don't need to store all of the stat bits you don't need -- you could do `my $mtime = (stat $filename)[9]` or you could load `File::stat` (core for the past 12 years) and do `my $mtime = stat($filename)->mtime`.

Comment: Agreed! (I pulled this out of a script I wrote ~10 years ago, so it's definitely less than perfect, and I had to make lots of edits to it before it was fit to post.. e.g. I can't believe I didn't use `use strict; use warnings;`) :D

Answer (score 3):

Copying this directly from the PHP website: http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.imagerotate.php

> This example rotates an image 180
>   degrees - upside down.

```
<?php
// File and rotation
$filename = 'test.jpg';
$degrees = 180;

// Content type
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

// Load
$source = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);

// Rotate
$rotate = imagerotate($source, $degrees, 0);

// Output
imagejpeg($rotate);
?>
```

To output the file to a new filename, using previous example:

```
// Output
imagejpeg($rotate, "new-" . $filename);
?>
```

Comment: Yes. This will rotate an image. But how do I decide which images to rotate? I want a function which examines the image headers and checks whether it's been rotated by F-Spot. If it hasn't been, the function stops. If it has been, the function rotates the image by the appropriate amount.

F-Spot (and some other programmes, including some cameras), rotates images by adding a note to say the image has been rotated. Other programmes ignore that note, and don't show the image rotated. I want to find images which contain that note and rotate them properly.